# how to sum up database field value based on date in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table having two fields in it just like below given.

[image]

How to create a view that will sum TOT_HITS field's value till each date appeared in corresponding row in TODAY column like given below.

[image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an analytic function to perform the query with only a single table scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ddcb/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table( today, tot_hits ) As
SELECT DATE '2018-01-16', 5498 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-01-17', 4235 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM( tot_hits ) OVER ( ORDER BY today ) AS tot_hits_to_date
FROM   your_table t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ddcb/1/0)**:

```
|                TODAY | TOT_HITS | TOT_HITS_TO_DATE |
|----------------------|----------|------------------|
| 2018-01-16T00:00:00Z |     5498 |             5498 |
| 2018-01-17T00:00:00Z |     4235 |             9733 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Try This

```
SELECT
    Today,
    Hits,
    TillDate = Hits+NVL((SELECT SUM(Hits) FROM YourTable  WHERE Today < T.Today),0)
    FROM YourTable T
```